# Compare SQL Dates with greater & less than symbols?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, compare

I've using the basic Oracle SQL and I was just wondering if its possible to compare dates?
Like comparing a date to see if its larger than another one?

For Example:

date1 < SYSDATE

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table_name
 WHERE date1 operator  date2
```

Comparing Dates allows you to examine if date exists or if one date is less than, equal to, or greater than another date.

Relational operators (=, < , <=, >, >=, <>, !< , !>), and

Logical operators and Boolean predicates (IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, IN, BETWEEN, EXISTS, NOT EXISTS, and LIKE) are all supported for all the date and time data types.

Use DATEADD and DATEDIFF to add and subtract date and time data types.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

```
select case when sysdate > (sysdate - 1) then 'Greater-than' else 'Not greater-than' end as DateComp from dual
```

Result:

```
Greater-than
```

Please try for yourself.